# jQuery loop on carousel not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Adding a loop option does not make my carosel loop!

```
`jQuery('#third-carousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        loop: true 
    });`
```

Using: /jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Carosel script:http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration), the option is `wrap`, not `loop`.

```
wrap: 'circular'
```

Comment: @c14kaa Glad to help.  If your problem has been solved, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the hollow tick to the left of the answer.